# Best Method For Playing M4A file in iPhone App

Tags: iphone

Greetings,

I have a tableview where I have parsed an list of podcasts(m4a format).  I want to now play the podcasts.  I have seen Matt Gallaghers method but it seems a bit excessive for what I need.  I remember seeing a tutorial where you could play such a file in UIWebview but it doesn't seems to work.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString * basePath = [NSHomeDirectory() 
           stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

basePath=[basePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"//"];
basePath=[basePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];    

NSURL * baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString      
                             stringWithFormat:@"file:/%@//",basePath]]; 

NSString *html = @"<html><body><audio src=\"test.mp3\" 
                                      controls></audio></body></html>";
[self.view loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseURL];
```

I rewrote the code and got this to work, the catch was handling the blanks in the document base path that was causing issue for me.

Comment: Aaron, thanks for your help but it is still not working.  What is playerWebView?